# Schema Field Type for Date.now() in Meteor-Simple-Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app I'm using `Date.now()` to create a timestamp for using in a new document that I'm inserting into Mongodb. `Date.now()` seems very well suited for my app. However I'm not very familiar with handling dates and times.

Now that I'm making the switch to `aldeed:simple-schema`, is it best practice to use `Date.now()` or convert it to another format? For the schema type, do we use `datetime` or `datetime-local`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime-local, however in order to do that you will have to access the Date() objects setters and set the objects value to the current local time of your area. Check out this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date